# Backbone - Model validation not called and "invalid" event not caught

Tags: validation, backbone.js, event-handling, marionette

I'm using Backbone and Marionette, I'm retrieving my models from a backend.
The models belong to a collection.
The problems are: 
1) The validate method is never called unless explicitly from within the initialize. Why?
2) When I explicitly call the validate method, it correctly returns for an invalid model I created for testing. But I am not able to catch the "invalid" event. What am I doing wrong?
Here's the model:

```
 var Job = Backbone.Model.extend({
    validate: function(attrs){
        if (! attrs.title ) {
            return "A job should have a title";
        }
    },

    initialize: function(){

        this.validate(this.attributes); //manual call to validate
        this.on("invalid",  function(model, error){ //never executed even when the validate model returns the error string
            console.log(error);
        });

    }

});
```

And here the Collection:

```
var JobList = Backbone.Collection.extend({
        model: Job,
        url: '/api/1.0/jobs/',
        parse: function(response) {
          return response.results;
        }

    });
```

Comment: What version of Backbone are you using? The validation logic has changed a lot between 0.9.2, 0.9.9 and 0.9.10.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I'm using Backbone 0.9.10, supposed to be the latest one. As I know in older versions the event fired was "error", not "invalid"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The validation logic was changed in Backbone `0.9.10`. Quoting from the [change log](http://backbonejs.org/#changelog), validation now works as follows:

> Model validation is now only enforced by default in Model#save and no longer enforced by default upon construction or in Model#set, unless the {validate:true} option is passed.

So if you want the model to be validated upon initialization or `set`, you need to pass the option `validate:true` to the constructor / method.

The reason you are not receiving the `invalid` event when you manually call your `model.validate` method is that Backbone is **not performing any of the validation** when you do. You call a method you defined on the model, and Backbone doesn't know anything about it.

Model validation in Backbone is convention based in the sense that Backbone doesn't define a method called `validate` on the model - you do yourself. However, if you have defined such a method, Backbone will call it for you when validation occurs (on `save`, or in constructor/setter with `validate:true`, and the `invalid` event will be triggered.

Comment: Thank you! In my case I'm not instanciating directly the single models, I'm retrieving them using the "fetch" method. Maybe this might help someone: `jobList = new JobList();
jobList.fetch({validate:true});`